# Mostrar e ocultar DIV de acordo com o nível do usuário

Tags: javascript

Preciso exibir alguns elementos `div` de acordo com o nível do usuário logado. Se o usurário for nível um só pode amostrar determinadas `div`'s. Segue abaixo a exibição:

```
<div id="hmn0" style="margin-top:0px;">
    <nav>
        <div id="acdnmenu" style="width:199px;height:390px;">
            <ul>
              <li id="v_sm">Administrativo
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./adm/cd_reqequip.php" target="main">Requisição de equipamentos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./adm/cd_document.php" target="main">Documentações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./cadastro.php" target="main">Cadastro</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="v_tt">Faturamento
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="./faturamento/cd_guiahm.php" target="main">Honorário Médico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./faturamento/cd_lancsessao.php" target="main">Lançar sessões</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./faturamento/cad_lancconta.php" target="main">Lançar na conta</a></li>
                        <li><a href="./faturamento/fat_unidade.php" target="main">Fatura por unidades</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: No meu caso em .NET criava o HTML no back-end e renderizava conforme a regra do nível do usuário.

Comment: Postei uma solução bem genérica, podem existir inúmeras variações de acordo com o seu contexto específico. Se puder informar mais detalhes, posso refinar a minha solução.

Answer (score 2):

Uma implementação bem genérica poderia ser:

```
function exibirDivDeAcordoComNivelDoUsuario(usuario) {
    if(usuario.nivel !== 1) {
        document.getElementById("hmn0").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Tenho um sistema com níveis de usuário, que são três níveis e apos a tela de login entram na pagina de MENU, uma pagina que possui vários DIV's com links para outras paginas... mas gostaria que só aparecesse certos DIV's de acordo com o nível do usuário que logou  ...  Estou usando PHP e HTML ... Já consegui bloquear para que o usuário não acesse a pagina dependendo do nível dele, mas o DIV na pagina de MENU ainda aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Como vc não especificou em que ambiente servidor é o seu site, vou dar um exemplo simples em ASP (VBScript):

Crio uma Session com o nível do usuário quando ele faz login:

```
session("user_nivel") = 1
```

No HTML, eu só mostro para o nível 1 o que eu quiser, assim:

```
<%if session("user_nivel") >= 2 then%>
<div>
  Esta div só é visível para nível 2 acima
</div>
<%end if%>

<%if session("user_nivel") = 1 then%>
<div>
  Esta div é visível somente para nível 1
</div>
<%end if%>
```

Se vc está utilizando PHP, a ideia é a mesma.

> Não faça isso em JavaScript porque pode ser burlado. O melhor é que a
>   `div` já venha ausente do servidor.

Comment: Acredito que estou fazendo algo errado, em php estou deixando assim    <?php
  session_start ();
  
  $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = 1; 
  ?>